# How to disable inspection for a specific class in Android studio "Arctic fox" release

Tags: android, android-studio

In previous android studio releases we used to have a button (in the bottom right side) that would enable you to disable inspections and do syntax check only .

But since I have updated to android studio arctic fox I am unable to find this button any more (I am not sure if it is disabled by default or if I have somehow disabled it).

is there a way to achieve this ? or add this shortcut back again .

Kindly check the images below .

[image: android studio arctic fox]

[image: previous android studio I had]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find out how to do it by chance .

From the top right side of the  IDE where you type your code . There is a small area that provide counters of errors and warning within the file .
click on it .then click on highlight options.
you have 3 options : None, Syntax and all problems .

checkout the screenshot for more details .

[image]